# What are the benefits of running a bitcoin daemon?

Tags: bitcoind, nodes, transit-fees

Can I get some fees on others transactions coming through my PC (creating blocks or whatever)? Transit-fees I mean.

Can I get some tiny bits of newly mined BTCs just on keep running bitcoind.exe in the background in 2013 and later?

Any other profits of keeping the full bitcoin database instead of using lite thin clients like MultiBit?

The bad side of MultiBit is you can not set the full zero fee. Official bitcoin wallet does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not get anything money wise from running bitcoind, however the Bitcoin network depends on people running it for verifications.  Its providing a service to the rest of the bitcoin community.  I run it because I participate in the bitcoin community and want to give something back.

This is how the "decentralized" part of the bitcoin protocol works.  People like you and I run the daemon and it verifies everyone elses transactions, the more people who run bitcoind the more secure the network becomes.

As for your other questions, I can't speak to speculation and this website will suspend your posts if you ask opinion or theoritical questions.

Comment: Everyone verifies every transaction from themselves. You don't rely on other unknown people running bitcoind to verify transactions for you because you have no reason to trust them.

Answer (score -1):

If you develop a client that:

1. allows the user to provide the private key of an address that has bitcoin in it,
2. offers to pay a small fee from that address to peers that provide blocks,
3. provide blocks (when it has them) to peers that request them in return for a fee,
4. loads the UTXO set as of some block from a trusted source, and
5. only requests the blocks it really needs,

...then maybe, someday, if bandwidth is highly constrained and therefore downloading the blockchain is very difficult, your client could make things easier for others and earn you some btc for it.

I'm not sure this is a good idea, which is why I asked [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/39019/must-block-contents-be-stored-with-the-proof-that-they-havent-been-changed).  I look forward to comments.